# How to force a DLL dependency even when no symbols are directly used by EXE?

Tags: c++, dll

I have A.DLL that depends on B.DLL. A.DLL contains some initialization code (`DllMain`) that registers stuff with B.DLL.

I also have executable E.EXE that does not directly reference any A.DLL symbols but it uses A.DLL's stuff through generic interfaces obtained from B.DLL.

The problem is that A.DLL is never loaded into E.EXE's process because none of its exported symbols are imports of E.EXE.

Can I force A.DLL to be loaded into the process without actually referencing A.DLL's symbols in E.EXE and without inverting the dependency (or creating a dependency loop) between A.DLL and B.DLL, and without using explicit `LoadLibrary()` call?

EDIT: The problem has been produced on Windows with Visual Studio but portability is a concern, thus `LoadLibrary()` is not usable.

Comment: What's wrong with `LoadLibrary()`. It's a single line of code!

Comment: What purpose does putting the DLL into the process serve here?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It is not portable and I do not want to deal with security issues related to manual DLL loading.

Comment: @wilx: not portable to which platform?

Comment: If portability is a goal you should say that in your question. Labeling it with visual studio and not mentioning portability will cause people to assume windows only.

Comment: @IgorKorkhov: Everything non-Windows.

Comment: @JaredPar: True. I have changed the tags and added a note into the question text.

Comment: @wilx Can't believe you forgot to mention portability. You only get DLLs on Windows! And as for security issues, what security issues? Implicit linking is no different from `LoadLibrary` and indeed with `LoadLibrary` you can control which DLL you load. You can't with implicit linking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the [/INCLUDE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s3hwbhs.aspx) linker option and provide a symbol exported by `A.dll`.

Even though your executable does not really reference that symbol, that option will force the linker to add `A.dll` to the dependencies.